# Nested json objects in Solr

Tags: solr, nested

I've tried the guide in http://yonik.com/solr-nested-objects/, but somehow it didn't work for me when trying to return the child documents with parent Id.

I'm using the latest version of Solr, which is Solr 8.1.0 in my case.

Using below code to return book1's comments with parent.

```
q = cat_s: (fantasy OR sci - fi) & fl = id, [child parentFilter = type_s: book]
```

The error message says as below:

```
{  
   "responseHeader":{  
      "status":400,
      "QTime":70,
      "params":{  
         "q":"cat_s:(fantasy OR sci-fi)",
         "fl":"id,[child parentFilter=type_s:book]",
         "_":"1560502563083"
      }
   },
   "error":{  
      "metadata":[  
         "error-class",
         "org.apache.solr.common.SolrException",
         "root-error-class",
         "org.apache.solr.common.SolrException"
      ],
      "msg":"Parent filter should not be sent when the schema is nested",
      "code":400
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix this I had to Edit managed-schema.xml by commenting out the line --> like so

Comment: Please, put a snippet example from your file to make this answer more clear.